# MVC - use validationmessagefor in jquery dialogbox on error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm trying to get the validationmessage work when a dialogbox loads a partial view but there are validation errors, and I'm having problem with this.

Here is part of the js code:

```
 buttons: {
        "Save": {
            text: 'Save',
            class: 'dialogBtnBlue',
            click: function (event, ui) {
                var form = $('#dayoff');
                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    async: true,
                    type: "POST",
                    url: form.attr('action'),
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    success: function () {

                        $("#newHolidayWindow").dialog('close');
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        $('#_page_'+ counter).load("PublicHolidaysTable", { id: id, page: counter });
                    },
                    error: function () {
                       // HERE


                    },
```

I would need this to happen in error, when I test it with 'alert ('fill in field'), it works, all I have to do is to properly set it up but I have no idea how to, I've tried many things.

Here is the view:

```
     @model Coats.TimeOFFEntMvcWeb.Models.Days_Off

<div class="grid" style="width: 600px !important;margin-top: -30px;">
     @using (Html.BeginForm("AddNewPublicHoliday_Create", "Administration", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "dayoff" }))
     { 
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="row">
        <h3 style="font-weight: bold">Adding Public Holiday</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <h3>Date</h3>
        <h4>Select public holiday date.</h4>
        <div class="input-control text span3" >
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Region_ID)
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
            </div>
    </div>
             <div class="row" style="width: 800px">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <h4>Fill in public holiday name.</h4>

                 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Region_ID)

                 <div class="input-control text span3">
                     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Days_Off_Name)
                     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Days_Off_Name)
                 </div>
</div>

        } 
</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

the 2 actions used for this:

```
        public ActionResult AddNewPublicHoliday(long id)
    {
        Days_Off day = new Days_Off() { Region_ID = id };


        return PartialView(day);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddNewPublicHoliday_Create(Day_Off day)
    {

            db = new Entities();
            db.Days_Off.Add(day);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");


    }
```

The dialog box loads AddNewPublicHoliday (which is where I would want the validation messages to show, as they would on a regular page). AddNewPublicHoliday_Create only exists as Post and is called by beginform as you can see.

Any suggestions on how I should do this without drastically changing the way my js code looks like?

Answer (score 0):

It's because jquery validate plugin is loaded on dom load. You should parse your dynamic form which wasn't here in begin.

```
var form = $("#myForm");
form.removeData('validator');
form.removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
```

Comment: Although this probably is also probably part of the problem, I'm also having trouble of what should put in the js code after 'error' where it's commented //HERE. Do I just load the same View through the Action?

Comment: It's the place to warn your user that there are an error and the view cannot be loaded. For example you can display a message error (with alert or a div which display the error)